# 3D pose estimation plot is skewed. Is it a problem with the camera calibration or the plotting?

Tags: python, plot, 3d

This is my code for the camera calibration (from https://temugeb.github.io/opencv/python/2021/02/02/stereo-camera-calibration-and-triangulation.html)

```
def calibrate_camera(images_folder):
    images_names = sorted(glob.glob(images_folder))
    images = []
    for imname in images_names:
        im = cv.imread(imname, 1)
        images.append(im)
 
    #criteria used by checkerboard pattern detector.
    #Change this if the code can't find the checkerboard
    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
 
    world_scaling = 1. #change this to the real world square size. Or not.
 
    #coordinates of squares in the checkerboard world space
    objp = np.zeros((rows*columns,3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:rows,0:columns].T.reshape(-1,2)
    objp = world_scaling* objp
 
    #frame dimensions. Frames should be the same size.
    width = images[0].shape[1]
    height = images[0].shape[0]
 
    #Pixel coordinates of checkerboards
    imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
 
    #coordinates of the checkerboard in checkerboard world space.
    objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
 
    for frame in images:
        gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
        #find the checkerboard
        ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (rows, columns), None)
 
        if ret == True:
 
            #Convolution size used to improve corner detection. Don't make this too large.
            conv_size = (11, 11)
 
            #opencv can attempt to improve the checkerboard coordinates
            corners = cv.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, conv_size, (-1, -1), criteria)
            #cv.drawChessboardCorners(frame, (rows,columns), corners, ret)
            #cv.imshow('img', frame)
            #k = cv.waitKey(500)
 
            objpoints.append(objp)
            imgpoints.append(corners)
 
 
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, (width, height), None, None)
    print('rmse:', ret)
    print('camera matrix:\n', mtx)
    print('distortion coeffs:', dist)
    print('Rs:\n', rvecs)
    print('Ts:\n', tvecs)
 
    return mtx, dist

    rows,columns = 6,4 
    
    def stereo_calibrate(mtx1, dist1, mtx2, dist2, frames_folder):
        #read the synched frames
        images_names = glob.glob(frames_folder)
        images_names = sorted(images_names)
        c1_images_names = images_names[:len(images_names)//2]
        c2_images_names = images_names[len(images_names)//2:]
     
        c1_images = []
        c2_images = []
        for im1, im2 in zip(c1_images_names, c2_images_names):
            _im = cv.imread(im1, 1)
            c1_images.append(_im)
     
            _im = cv.imread(im2, 1)
            c2_images.append(_im)
     
        #change this if stereo calibration not good.
        criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 500, 0.0001)
     
        world_scaling = 2. #change this to the real world square size. Or not.
     
        #coordinates of squares in the checkerboard world space
        objp = np.zeros((rows*columns,3), np.float32)
        objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:rows,0:columns].T.reshape(-1,2)
        objp = world_scaling* objp
     
        #frame dimensions. Frames should be the same size.
        width = c1_images[0].shape[1]
        height = c1_images[0].shape[0]
     
        #Pixel coordinates of checkerboards
        imgpoints_left = [] # 2d points in image plane.
        imgpoints_right = []
     
        #coordinates of the checkerboard in checkerboard world space.
        objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
     
        for frame1, frame2 in zip(c1_images, c2_images):
            gray1 = cv.cvtColor(frame1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            gray2 = cv.cvtColor(frame2, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            c_ret1, corners1 = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray1, (rows, columns), None)
            c_ret2, corners2 = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray2, (rows, columns), None)
     
            if c_ret1 == True and c_ret2 == True:
                corners1 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray1, corners1, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
                corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray2, corners2, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
    
     
                objpoints.append(objp)
                imgpoints_left.append(corners1)
                imgpoints_right.append(corners2)
     
        stereocalibration_flags = cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
        ret, CM1, dist1, CM2, dist2, R, T, E, F = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints, imgpoints_left, imgpoints_right, mtx1, dist1,
                                                                     mtx2, dist2, (width, height), criteria = criteria, flags = stereocalibration_flags)
     
        print(ret)
        return R, T
    
    R, T = stereo_calibrate(mtx1, dist1, mtx2, dist2, '/calibration/synched/*')

#RT matrix for C1 is identity.
RT1 = np.concatenate([np.eye(3), [[0],[0],[0]]], axis = -1)
P1 = mtx1 @ RT1 #projection matrix for C1
 
#RT matrix for C2 is the R and T obtained from stereo calibration.
RT2 = np.concatenate([R, T], axis = -1)
P2 = mtx2 @ RT2 #projection matrix for C2

def DLT(P1, P2, point1, point2):
 
    A = [point1[1]*P1[2,:] - P1[1,:],
         P1[0,:] - point1[0]*P1[2,:],
         point2[1]*P2[2,:] - P2[1,:],
         P2[0,:] - point2[0]*P2[2,:]
        ]
    A = np.array(A).reshape((4,4))
    #print('A: ')
    #print(A)
 
    B = A.transpose() @ A
    from scipy import linalg
    U, s, Vh = linalg.svd(B, full_matrices = False)
 
    print('Triangulated point: ')
    print(Vh[3,0:3]/Vh[3,3])
    return Vh[3,0:3]/Vh[3,3]

p3ds = []
for uv1, uv2 in zip(uvs1, uvs2):
    _p3d = DLT(P1, P2, uv1, uv2)
    p3ds.append(_p3d)
p3ds = np.array(p3ds)
```

Everything works so far. However, when I want to plot the key points in a 3D scatter like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a DataFrame for your triangulated points
df = pd.DataFrame(p3ds, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])

# Plot the 3D scatter plot
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='x', y='y', z='z', color='z', 
                     color_continuous_scale='Viridis')

# Define connections between points
connections = [[0,3], [0,4], [3,4],[0,5], [0,6], [5,6],
               [5,7], [7,9], [6,8], [8,10], [11,12],
               [5,11], [6, 12], [11,13],[13,15],
               [12,14], [14, 16]]

# Add connections to the plot
for c in connections:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[p3ds[c[0],0], p3ds[c[1],0]],
                                y=[p3ds[c[0],1], p3ds[c[1],1]],
                                z=[p3ds[c[0],2], p3ds[c[1],2]],
                                mode='lines',
                                line=dict(color='red', width=2)))

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

From this perspective you can see that it's skewed (the person is standing upright)

[image: 1]

From this perspective it looks okay, I guess?

[image: 2]

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Is my camera calibration incorrect or the plotting? Am I missing something? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the plotting is broken. fix that first. the axes aren't scaled equally. look at the range of each axis. -- as for the rest, not reproducible. you haven't provided a [mre]. part of a MRE is the required input data. another part is pruning the code, throwing everything out that doesn't contribute to the issue. my asking for this doesn't imply that I'll have the time to actually run anything.